# Google fit API in java

Tags: api, playframework, google-fit

How I can able to integrate Google FIT API in java using Play framework. I don't want to make a maven project. I have try to get URL using oAuth 2 playground

Comment: Do you wish to package the FIT API into your application or call the web services?

Comment: I want to call the web services

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

SBT can download from maven repos. Did you try it ?

Maven dependency that looks like (**you do not need this in your play project**, it just for example to show how to convert maven dependency to sbt)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

could be added to the built.sbt as a **library dependencies** (only this must be added to the sbt project)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.20.0"
)
```

Then just rebuild the project. I got successful resolving of this lib:

```
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.api-client#google-api-client;1.20.0!google-api-client.jar (407ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.20.0/google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.oauth-client#google-oauth-client;1.20.0!google-oauth-client.jar (248ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/1.20.0/google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson2;1.20.0!google-http-client-jackson2.jar (124ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/13.0/guava-jdk5-13.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.guava#guava-jdk5;13.0!guava-jdk5.jar (1248ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.20.0/google-http-client-1.20.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.20.0!google-http-client.jar (315ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question but I do not want to use Maven project. Can you please suggest me how I can do with out using maven project

Comment: It's not about Maven -it's about SBT. You can include dependency from maven in to sbt project, like play. So you will not be use maven project.  You need to add only "library dependencies" - i put "Maven dependency " just to show you how you can convert it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the REST API then you do not necessarily need to package any of the Android Jars in your application since you are just consuming JSON from the web service. The following resources are useful if you haven't already found them. You will need to authenticate your clients with Google's API using OAuth.

**Play**
[Play Java WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaWS)

**Google FIT**
[Get Started with the Google REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started)
[Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) the Get Started guide describes how to use the Playground

**Some Play specific OAuth resources**
[Secure Social](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial)
[Play Authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)